# No results when in the mapping, the field _all has specified an index_analyzer

Tags: search, elasticsearch

With Elasticsearch I have created an index using a custom mapping and custom set of analszers, however I'm not able to do query search on the _all field.

I'm using these analyzers:

```
{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "case_insensitive": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "keyword",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "asciifolding"
                ],
                "char_filter": "punctuation"
            }
        },
        "char_filter": {
            "punctuation": {
                "type": "mapping",
                "mappings": [
                    ".=>\\u0020",
                    "-=>\\u0020",
                    "_=>\\u0020"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this mapping:

```
{
"article": {
    "_all": {
        "enabled": true,
        "store": "yes",
        "index_analyzer": "case_insensitive",
        "search_analyzer": "case_insensitive"
    },
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "analyzed"
        },
        "subtitle": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
        },
        "comment": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "review": {
            "type":"string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "include_in_all":false
        }
    }
}
```

}

Then I add a document like this:

```
{
    "title": "This is the story of a wonderful man.", 
    "subtitle":"A man goes on vacation in the worst place possible.",
    "comment": "I like the movie very much, however I did not undertand it.",
    "review":"Very well"
}
```

and I expect the following 3 out of 4 fields shall be included in _all, in particular title, subtitle and comment.

The analyzer is working as following (tested using the analyzer test in elasticsearch):

"I like the movie very much, however I did not undertand it." -> "i like the movie very much, however i did not undertand it "

"This is the story of a wonderful man." -> "this is the story of a wonderful man "

I expect that at least searching on _all using the query: "This is the story of a wonderful man." I should be able to find the document.

What am I doing wrong?

How is elasticsearch populating the _all field?

If the field 'title' shall be added to the _all field, which data is used and how? is it using the output of the analyzer selected for the 'title' field as input for the analyzer of the _all or is using the raw data?

How is the flow of data in the _all field? For example

input -> analyzer -> title -> index_analyser -> _all

or

input -> analyzer -> title 
      -> index_analyser -> _all

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping looks ok to me. The only thing I would try is to set one of the fields explicitly to `include_in_all=true` and then rerun your query.

According to the docs, it may be that as you are overriding the default value of `include_in_all` for one of the fields, it may have changed it for all the other fields of the objects. See here [_all](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/root-object.html#all-field)

Relevant text from the documentation is below:

> Inclusion in the _all field can be controlled on a field-by-field basis by using the include_in_all setting, which defaults to true. Setting include_in_all on an object (or on the root object) changes the default for all fields within that object.

**UPDATE:**

I think I know why its not working. Here is what I did. First, I removed the custom analysers from the `_all_` field (so using the standard analyser). With this I was able to query and get the results as expected. Results were returned for terms that were in any of the document attributes but **review**. At least this confirms that the general behaviour of `_all` is correct. Next to test the analysers, I did a query on the **subtitle** field with the exact text(as it is using keyword analyser). This also worked. Then I realised that `_all` is an aggregated field and **then** analysed.

So the query should include all the text from all the fields to work. But again, how do we know in which order they were aggregated :)

This link [_all custom analyser](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Specifying-analyzer-for-all-field-td3851732.html) has some information. Relevant bits extracted below (from Shay).

> You don't want to set the analyzer for _all to be keyword, _all is an aggregation of all the other fields int the doc, so you basically treat the whole aggregation of text as a single token.

Comment: Dear jrao77. Thanks for your answer. I've tried what you said by adding explicitly include_in_all:true in all the attribute (altought they are on the same level of depth) of the object (title, subtitle, etc) but it didn't improve the results.

Comment: Have you re-indexed the document after the mapping change? Without re-indexing the query will produce the same results (even with the updated mapping).

Comment: Yes, of course. I've dropped the index, re-created, and re-indexed.

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer make sense. 
I have created an additional analyzer, which uses the whitespace tokenizer instead of the keyword and applied as index_analyzer for the _all field. Seems to work fine.